# Swap rows between two dataframes with a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, swap

I have 2 dataframes looking like this :

In each dataframe there is pattern of 1-2 in the values column. (the values are not significant to my problem, just to demonstrate the pattern)

```
df1 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [20, 1000, 10001, 21, 1000, 1002, 22, 1003, 1007,23]}
df2 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [1000, 21, 22, 1000, 22, 23, 1000, 20, 21, 1000]}
```

I need to swap rows between the two dataframes so that the outcome would be :

```
df_expected1 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [20, 21, 22, 21, 22, 23, 22, 20, 21,23]}

df_expected2 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [1000, 1000, 10001, 1000, 1000, 1002, 1000, 1003, 1007, 1000]}
```

Comment: What would be the condition to swap? if greater or equal to 1000? or sequential (1, 2, 1, 2, 1)?

Comment: @Chris the sequence , because the values can be identical between the two sometimes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowing that swap-needed indices are from `3n-2`, you can make mask then use `numpy.where`:

```
m = df1["idx"].add(2).mod(3).eq(0)
s1 = np.where(m, df1["values"], df2["values"])
s2 = np.where(~m, df1["values"], df2["values"])

df1["values"] = s1
df2["values"] = s2
```

Output:

```
   idx  values
0    1      20
1    2      21
2    3      22
3    4      21
4    5      22
5    6      23
6    7      22
7    8      20
8    9      21
9   10      23

   idx  values
0    1    1000
1    2    1000
2    3   10001
3    4    1000
4    5    1000
5    6    1002
6    7    1000
7    8    1003
8    9    1007
9   10    1000
```

Comment: If you have a big dataframe, this solution is faster than mine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, knowing that the indices are the same between two dataframes :

```
df1[df1['idx']%3 == 1], df2[df1['idx']%3 == 1] = df2[df1['idx']%3 == 1], df1[df1['idx']%3 == 1]
```

Output :

```
   idx  values
 0    1    1000
 1    2    1000
 2    3   10001
 3    4    1000
 4    5    1000
 5    6    1002
 6    7    1000
 7    8    1003
 8    9    1007
 9   10    1000
    idx  values
 0    1      20
 1    2      21
 2    3      22
 3    4      21
 4    5      22
 5    6      23
 6    7      22
 7    8      20
 8    9      21
 9   10      23
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet below, I assumed that indexes in both `df1` and `df2` were equal and that values from `df1` are always supposed to be greater than `df2`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pprint import pprint

df1 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [20, 1000, 10001, 21, 1000, 1002, 22, 1003, 1007,23]}
df2 = {'idx': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'values': [1000, 21, 22, 1000, 22, 23, 1000, 20, 21, 1000]}

a = pd.DataFrame(df1).set_index('idx')
b = pd.DataFrame(df2).set_index('idx')

col_name = 'values'
a_series = a[col_name]
b_series = b[col_name]
for i in a_series.index:
    if a_series.loc[i] > b_series.loc[i]:
        a_series.loc[i], b_series.loc[i] = b_series.loc[i], a_series.loc[i]

df_expected1 = {'idx': a_series.index.tolist(), 'values': a_series.values.tolist()}
df_expected2 = {'idx': b_series.index.tolist(), 'values': b_series.values.tolist()}

pprint(df_expected1)
pprint(df_expected2)
```

Output:

```py
{'idx': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 'values': [1000, 1000, 10001, 1000, 1000, 1002, 1000, 1003, 1007, 1000]}
{'idx': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 'values': [20, 21, 22, 21, 22, 23, 22, 20, 21, 23]}
```

Comment: OP said that values could be identical sometimes